# i want to achieve a round strip led lights at the bottom inside of a container with glass shader in order to light up the whole glass

Tags: shaders, lighting, glass

[image: looking to create something like this i have already created the 3d model but stuck on this lighting problem also i want to create the scribbles on the bottle]

i wander around some shaders and did some experiments but nothing so far and btw i am using eevee engine

Comment: Please show your work as Blender screen captures and renders.  Then your question can become more focused.  Focused question with one topic is better than the question above.  The question above seems like you seeking to have help on too many different project responsibilities.

Comment: The are many video tutorials on a glass and ordinary lights on the video site that rhymes with noonoob.  That could be  a starting  point for you.

Comment: okay ....just help me with the lightning solution...........................if you can

Comment: Please show your work.  Mesh targeted for light  can just have an emission material.  The light can just be a set of boxes (scaled), in one mesh for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it all with a shader, you could do something like this. All I did was make some vertical stripes with a Wave texture (I isolated the X and Y and normalized them so there would be 2 "banks" of LED's). All I did after that was make a mask for where the lights will go (vertically) and use that as a mix factor between a Glass Shader and an Emission shader that is colored by the "lights" I made with the Wave Texture.

[image: LedGlass]

If you darken the ambient lighting, you can see it lights up the glass. You can increase the light propagation by increasing the roughness of the Glass Shader slightly, you can also increase the IOR - however, the proper IOR for glass is 1.45 - too high a value, and things will start to look unrealistic, especially from certain angles. Find a balance that works best for you.

Lastly, you can increase the emission strength, but also beware that too strong a value may start to "wash out" some of the colors.

[image: LedGlass2]